# Failed with error: ‘packages could not be loaded’

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

Executing the script below is generating an error that did not occur before.

**Here's my code:**

```
Pacotes <- c("MethComp","qqplotr","imputeTS","multiway","prettydoc","moments",
             "mclust","ggQC","stats","ffp","RVAideMemoire","forecast","AID",
             "ggplot2","nortest","rmarkdown","gt","MASS","plotly","ggpubr",
             "readxl","calibrate","mixtools","knitr","kableExtra","modeest",
             "dplyr","cluster","factoextra","FactoMineR","DT","cartography",
             "data.table","devtools","univOutl","multimode","mixR",
             "refineR","KernSmooth")


if(sum(as.numeric(!Pacotes %in% installed.packages())) != 0){
  instalador <- Pacotes[!Pacotes %in% installed.packages()]
  for(i in 1:length(instalador)) {
    install.packages(instalador, dependencies = TRUE)
    break()}
  sapply(Pacotes, require, character = TRUE)
  } else {
    sapply(Pacotes, require, character = TRUE)
  }
```

Failed with error:  'package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded'

Failed with error:  'package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded'

Failed with error:  'package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded'

Failed with error:  'package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded'

Failed with error:  'package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded'

Failed with error:  'package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded'

**Can anybody help me? Why is this error occurring?**

The error started to occur after installing the latest version of R and RStudio on my notebook that has the Windows 10 Pro operating system.

Comment: If you are looping over the sequence of `instalador`, why is there no `i` index inside `installl.packages`

Comment: the code worked normally before. Now it started showing this error.